# Switch ContentControl with MenuItems

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am very new to WPF and MVVM and hopelessly lost. I'm trying to create a simple window with several views that are switchable through a MenuItem and I've run into two problems:

1. How can I build a list of menu items dynamically? (View 1, View 2, View 3 in the attached picture).
2. How can I add commands to these menu items to change the view?

[image: Demo window showing the desired output.]

Here is my current code to generate the window. Currently it does not change views. My MainWindow contains the Menu bar and a ContentControl that will hold the view. ContentControl's content is intended to be switched between three UserControl's called UserControl1, UserControl2, UserControl3.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:View="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3.View"
    xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3.ViewModel"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:UserControl1ViewModel}">
        <View:UserControl1/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:UserControl2ViewModel}">
        <View:UserControl2/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:UserControl3ViewModel}">
        <View:UserControl3/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="22"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Header="Quit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="144.506666666667"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="_View">
            <MenuItem Header="View 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="144.506666666667"/>
            <MenuItem Header="View 2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="144.506666666667"/>
            <MenuItem Header="View 3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="144.506666666667"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding View}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
</Grid>
```

And here is my WIP viewmodel for the main window. I was following [this](http://www.japf.fr/2009/03/thinking-with-mvvm-data-templates-contentcontrol/) tutorial as a starting point and trying to modify it to fit my needs.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication3.ViewModel
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly ObservableCollection<ControlViewModelBase> views;
        private int selectedView;

        public ControlViewModelBase View
        {
            get { return views[selectedView]; }
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            selectedView = 0;
            this.views = new ObservableCollection<ControlViewModelBase>();

            views.Add(new UserControl1ViewModel());
            views.Add(new UserControl2ViewModel());
            views.Add(new UserControl3ViewModel());
        }
    }
}
```

My previous attempt looked very WinForms-like and had lots of code behind to capture menu item clicks and switching of views. I'm trying to use MVVM and databinding to achieve this but since I'm still trying to wrap my head around these two concepts.

P.S. let me know if you need to see more code samples

Comment: Can you explain me one moment please? Different views have different logic or same logic with other view properties(such as background or font family etc.)? Thanks

Comment: Views have different logic.